# Residual Symmetry Group after Spontaneous Symmetry Breaking

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry-breaking

I am seeking a proof of the following:

Suppose we have a theory with $n$ scalar fields $(\phi_1,...,\phi_n)$  such that the Lagrangian $L$ is invariant under the action of some group $G$.

However, $G$ is a spontaneously broken symmetry: The vacuum expectation value (or the minimum of the potential) $\phi^{cl}$ is nonzero and is only invariant under a subgroup $H \subseteq G$.  I.e. we have for any $h \in H$:

$$ h \phi^{cl} = \phi^{cl} $$

which is to say every generator $g^j$ of $H$  satisfies $g^j_{ab} \phi^{\rm cl}_b = 0  $. Is there a general proof that when the Lagrangian is written in terms of shifted fields (i.e. those with 0 vacuum expectation value), it is only invariant under $H$ and not the entirety of $G$ and that $H$ is a manifest symmetry of the system.

Comment: I think you need to make your question more precise. A Lagrangian that is $G$-invariant will remain $G$-invariant upon any (nonsingular) change of field variables. Reparametrizing the fields does not change the symmetry, it only changes the way the symmetry is realized on the fields. If you are instead asking for a proof that only the subgroup $H$ remains "manifest" upon shifting the fields by the vacuum expectation value, then you should first define what you mean by "manifest".

Comment: meaning that the subgroup $H$ is a symmetry of the goldstone boson multiplet ($\phi_1,...,phi_N$) where $N$ is the number of broken generators, i.e. it leaves the Lagrangian invariant. Manifest = The minimum of the potential has $H$ as a symmetry.

Comment: The fact that $H$ (as well as the larger group $G$) leaves the Lagrangian invariant is your starting assumption. This is not affected by changing the parametrization of the fields. Moreover, your definition of "manifest" coincides with how the unbroken subgroup $H$ is defined to start with, so this doesn't get us anywhere.

Comment: The following statement is proven in Coleman, Wess and Zumino, Phys. Rev. 177 (1969) 2239. Suppose a Lie group $G$ acts on a set of fields $\phi^a$ via point transformations. (This means that the transformed fields only depend on the original fields and not on field derivatives or spacetime coordinates.) Suppose a particular point $\phi^a_0$ in the field space (you can call it ground state) is fixed by a subgroup $H\subseteq G$. Then, provided $H$ is compact, it is possible to change the field variables $\phi^a\to\psi^a$ so that $H$ is realized by *linear* transformations of $\psi^a$.